# flash messages in rails using turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Turbolinks in my Rails 5 app. Now it is behaving as single page app, which is good, but when I create a new user or sign up the flash errors are not showing up.

I'm betting the following error in the in console:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in 401 (Unauthorized)
Rails.ajax @ rails-ujs.self-817d9a8cb641f7125060cb18fefada3f35339170767c4e003105f92d4c204e39.js?body=1:189
Rails.handleRemote @ rails-ujs.self-817d9a8cb641f7125060cb18fefada3f35339170767c4e003105f92d4c204e39.js?body=1:546
(anonymous) @ rails-ujs.self-817d9a8cb641f7125060cb18fefada3f35339170767c4e003105f92d4c204e39.js?body=1:146
VM707:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at processResponse (rails-ujs.self-817d9a8cb641f7125060cb18fefada3f35339170767c4e003105f92d4c204e39.js?body=1:246)
    at rails-ujs.self-817d9a8cb641f7125060cb18fefada3f35339170767c4e003105f92d4c204e39.js?body=1:173
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (rails-ujs.self-817d9a8cb641f7125060cb18fefada3f35339170767c4e003105f92d4c204e39.js?body=1:23
```

What I really need is to show those errors in the view using by using the flash. Any suggestions would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also use Turbolinks 5 and have not problems with my flash error messages. so this are the errors you get, did you tought about investigating how does that syntaxerror:  Unexpected identifier looks like? maybe it is not what you think? maybe you should investigate more and add more info, because I don't see a clear solution to this problem right now

Comment: Which code do you use to trigger the route? 
This can be either problem with parameter which is not added to the strong parameters list, or can be something with Devise.